# Insert Dinámico en sql server

Tags: sql-server, variables, sql, insert, tabla-dinámica

Cordial saludo.

Quiero hacer una inserción de datos de una tabla a otra tabla pero de forma dinámica debido a la gran cantidad de datos que hay, ¿Como se podría realizar?.

Esta es la tabla de donde quiero extraer los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la tabla a la que quiero insertarle los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo deseo insertar los datos, las columnas ya las tengo listas.

He intentado colocando el insert dentro de una variable y despúes ejecutarla,pero me da el siguiente error: "Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name '34'.".

Así es como lo hago:

```
SET @IN=' INSERT INTO ##TABLE_TEMPED (TERMINAL) VALUES('+@TERMINAL+')';

EXEC(@IN);
```

La variable @TERMINAL contiene los valores de las terminales de la primera tabla.

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: por qué se tiene que hacer esto con SQL dinámico?

Comment: Esas tablas son de ejemplo,las que estoy utilizando contiene 200.000 filas y 268 columnas, por tal motivo es mejor hacer el INSERT dinámico que estático para no tener que copiar todas esas coolumnas y además se van a estar agreagando valores constantemente. Agradezco su ayuda si sabes como hacerlo dinámicamente.

Comment: Ya no se utiliza EXEC para los sql dinámicos. Mejor utiliza `EXEC sp_executesql @IN`. Recuerda que la variable que contiene el sql dinámico tiene que ser declarada como `VARCHAR(MAX)`. Aquí no te podemos ayudar, puesto que tu pregunta no es específica. Recomiendo buscar más acerca del tema en [la documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)